# Button Not showing in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that I'm using in asp.net MVC and the column won't display anything. It just returns empty.  I don't see the input in code when I use developer tools either.

```
columns.Template(@<text>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Tasks"
 onclick="window.location.href = '../../OBClientSetupTasks/Index/@item.SetupID'" />
            </text>).HeaderTemplate(@<text>Tools</text>);
          })
```

I don't understand what I'm missing as that value should display the button.

Comment: Server or ajax bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AJAX bound Kendo grids you need to use the `ClientTemplate` helper, and JS templates (`#= …#`) to incorporate values on the client side.